# What does this command "$(docker images -a -q)" mean?

Tags: docker, command-line

I'am looking for the answer to delete all container in docker. And I found

```
docker container rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
```

I know the command `docker ps -a -q` is show all id containers (both running and stop). but I don't understand why pass it as command's parameter `docker container rm -f`.

I have seen a lot of commands like this. So, what exactly is it? How can I test it before actual run?

---

After searching on google for a while, I found it in [here](https://blog.wplauncher.com/what-is-in-linux/)

It is called a **command substitution**

Comment: `docker container rm -f` deletes the containers you tell it to delete. `docker ps -a -q` gives you a list of all containers. To delete all the containers you need to tell it to delete ... a list of all the containers. ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks, maybe you don't understand what I mean. Adding the $() and adding the command in it, what is it actually?

Comment: @Quentin, Which keyword can I learn more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(...)` is a Unix/Linux shell notation that means 'run this command and put the output here'.

`docker ps -a -q` returns the ids of all containers on the machine. Both running and stopped.

Those ids are then passed into `docker container rm -f <ids>`. Because you have the `-f` flag on, both running and stopped containers will be removed.